# Remove uploaded images rails 4 carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Trying to remove uploaded images using carrierwave

```
<%= f.fields_for :images do |ff| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <%= ff.check_box :remove_image %>
          <%= image_tag ff.object.image %>
        </label>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Getting such params in controller

```
"images_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"remove_image"=>"0", "id"=>"13"}, "1"=>{"remove_image"=>"1", "id"=>"14"}, "2"=>{"remove_image"=>"0", "id"=>"15"}, "3"=>{"remove_image"=>"0", "id"=>"16"}, "4"=>{"remove_image"=>"0", "id"=>"17"}, "5"=>{"remove_image"=>"0", "id"=>"18"}}}
```

But when updating an object with these params nothing happens, what am I missing?

**update**

```
  def update
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])

    if @country.update(country_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Country is successfully updated.'
      redirect_to edit_admin_country_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @country.errors.full_messages[0]
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def country_params
    permitted = [{images_attributes: ["image", "@original_filename", "@content_type", "@headers", "_destroy", "id", "remove_image"]}]
    params.require(:country).permit(*permitted)
  end

 class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images
    ....
 end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :country
end
```

Comment: Is there any controller where to see how are you trying to remove such images?

Comment: kindly share your modal as well.

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your form looks good but you are missing the controller action

mine looks like:

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def update
    @image = Image.find(params[:id])
    ...
    if params[:images][:remove_image].present?
      @image.remove_image!
    end
    @image.save
  end
end
```

> If you want to remove the file manually, you can call remove_avatar!, then save the object.

Comment: I wanted to remove all images at once, I dont have a problem looping and deleting, hoped I could find a more elegant way

Comment: Thank you very much for your help anyway!